# nginx docker-compose issues mongo with node angular 5 on Windows

Tags: angular, docker, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have the following issue, when trying to create a user on the mongo container I am getting the below error.  when not using docker and not using the mongo container, but the mongo installed on my harddisk, the user is created with no issues.

I have very limited experience/knowledge with nginx and wonder if this config file is correct and when or if this config is setup for reverse proxy?

It feels as if the (app-js) mongo connection is not being made. 
I am using authentication on the docker-compose, should I also use the username and password to make the connection in the app.?

error:

```
 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
 main.1562976….bundle.js:1 t error
 :
 ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, 
 total: 0, type: "error", …}
 headers 
 :
 e {normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0)}
 message
 :
 "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
 name
```

app.js  (express server)

```
var connect = require('./models/user')
connect.connect('mongodb://mongo/loginapp'); 
var db = mongoose.connection;
```

default.conf nginx

```
   server {

 listen 80;
 sendfile on;
 default_type application/octet-stream;
 gzip on;
 gzip_http_version 1.1;
 gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
 gzip_min_length   1100;
 gzip_vary         on;
 gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
 gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json 
 application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml 
 application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;
 root /usr/share/nginx/html;
 location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
   }

   }
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
 services:
   web:
   build: ./
 ports:
  - "80:80"
 links:
  - node
  volumes:
   - "./dist :/usr/share/nginx/html"
 node:
 build: ./
  ports:
    - "3000:3000"
 links:
  - mongo
  mongo:
  environment:
  - AUTH=yes
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=superAdmin
  - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin123
  - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=d0c4ae452a5c
  image: mongo
  ports: 
 - "27017:27017"
```

Dockerfile

```
  ### STAGE 1: Build ###

 # We label our stage as ‘builder’
FROM node:8.1.4-alpine as builder

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./

## Storing node modules on a separate layer will prevent unnecessary npm 
 installs at each build
  RUN npm i && mkdir /ng-app && cp -R ./node_modules ./ng-app

WORKDIR /ng-app

COPY . .

 ## Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist 
 folder
 RUN $(npm bin)/ng build --prod


### STAGE 2: Setup ###

FROM nginx:1.13.3-alpine

## Copy our default nginx config
COPY nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

## Remove default nginx website
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

## From ‘builder’ stage copy over the artifacts in dist folder to default
nginx public folder
COPY --from=builder /ng-app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

docker ps gives me:

```
 CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND       CREATED     STATUS              PORTS                            NAMES
 a486ae0b16ac        meanchat_web        "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp               meanchat_web_1
 a37e8552abf2        meanchat_node       "nginx -g 'daemon ..."   10 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:3000->3000/tcp   meanchat_node_1
 ed9ccb5dbd80        mongo               "docker-entrypoint..."   11 minutes ago      Up 10 minutes       0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp         meanchat_mongo_1
```

Comment: What URL were you requesting for that failure? I don't see proxy setup in that nginx config - is your node app supposed to listen on a different port? Are you then calling the proper URL?

Comment: I am requesting a post http://192.168.2.11/api/register on port 3000, how do u mean different port to what? Should it standard be something else? Will the current config work? I am running basically 3 seperate containers, mongo/ nginx and node, I want to be able to develop as well so that it updates live like ng serve.

Comment: yi the routing does work on the app to for instance my dashboard template and register template, but the httpclient posts dont seem to work, even though it works using the normal non container database mongodb

Comment: Are you requesting 192.168.2.11/api/register or 192.168.2.11:3000/api/register?

Comment: y last one on port:3000, tried localhost and ip is correct, I can login on the container with the admin password this works, does the database create the loginapp database itself?

Comment: Hmm. Can you `curl http://192.168.2.11:3000/api/register -X POST -d '{}'` locally? What do you get as response?

Comment: empty reply from the server: curl: (52)